# Запуск программы в bash и продолжение скрипта

Tags: bash, cmd, shell, консоль

Запускаю баш-скрипт с

```
exec "/c/program.exe" && echo "ok"
```

Скрипт запуска программу и зависает - т.е. перестает выполняться дальше.

Как можно запустить программу и продолжить выполнение скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение

```
exec "/c/program.exe" & echo "ok"
```

Comment: такой вариант запустит program.exe и тут-же выдаст в консоль "ok". А если написать так: `(exec "/c/program.exe" && echo "ok") &`, то "ok" будет в консольке уже после выполнения program.exe (если тот вернят код ошибки == 0)

Comment: Тоже полезно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

вот примерно где и что можно воткнуть:

```
echo 'before start'
(
exec "/c/program.exe" &&
 echo "finished Success" ||
 echo "finished Failure"

echo "after finish any case"
) &

echo 'after start'
```

Comment: В чём смысл exec  здесь?

Comment: про exec обращайтесь к автору вопрося, я без понятия что это за Виндовая экибана ;-)

Comment: не стоит из вопроса код копировать, если вы не понимаете что он делает. Код в вопросе может вообще не работать. От ответа бо́льшего ожидается. Ваш ответ не только автор вопроса может прочитать (в этом соль Stack Overflow: один человек может поделиться крупицей знания со многими). Избегайте [cargo-cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)